A question about the norm of an ideal in the integer ring of an imaginary quadratic field
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ be the imaginary quadratic field with respect to a fundamental discriminant $D < 0$. Also, let $R$ be the integer ring of $K$ and $I \subset R$ be some integral ideal. As is known, there is the norm map $\mathrm{N}\!: K \to \mathbb{Q}$ for which the set-theoretic direct image $\mathrm{N}(R) \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Meanwhile, the norm of $I$ as an ideal in $R$ has the form $I\overline{I} = nR$, where $\overline{I}$ is the conjugate ideal of $I$ and $n := \#(R/I)$ is the norm of $I$ as a natural number. We see that $\mathrm{N}(I) \subset \mathrm{N}(R) \subset \mathbb{Z}$ as sets. Am I right or not that $\mathrm{N}(I)\mathbb{Z} = n\mathbb{Z}$?
More precisely, I am interested in the case when $I$ is a reduced ideal, that is, $I = a\mathbb{Z} + \dfrac{b + \sqrt{D}}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q(x,y) := ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is a reduced integral positive definite binary quadratic form, where $c := (b^2 - D)/(4a)$. In other words, $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ are such that $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $|b| \leqslant a \leqslant c$ and $b \geqslant 0$ if $a = c$ and besides $q(\mathbb{Z}^2) \subset \mathbb{N}$. It is readily seen that the image $\mathrm{N}(I) = aq(\mathbb{Z}^2)$. In the given case, the numerical norm $n = a$, but I don't see why $a$ generates (or at least lies in) $\mathrm{N}(I)\mathbb{Z}$. Tell me please I am mistaken somewhere or not.

This property holds for any ideal in the ring of integers of any number field and it's a reasonably well-known result within algebraic number theory.
But we can generalize further to any extension of number fields $L/K$. The statement in question follows by taking $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{D})$ and $K=\Bbb Q$. In fact, there's an even more general theorem, which holds for any (generically separable) extension of Dedekind domains. I'll prove this general version.
Let's introduce some notation. Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with fraction field $K$ and let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension and let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Then $S$ is again a Dedekind domain and $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module (finite generation uses the separability of $L/K$).
First of all, to even state the proper generalization, we need a notion of a (relative) ideal norm $N_{S/R}(I)$ for an ideal $I \leq S$. As $R$ is not necessarily a PID, it would be unreasonable to expect $N_{S/R}(I)$ to be an integer or an element of $R$, in fact it will be an ideal of $R$. The norm for elements $N_{L/K}:L \to K$ is defined just like in the number field case.
The approach I'll take to define $N_{S/R}(I)$ uses the Jordan-Hölder theorem for modules. For convenience, I'll recapitulate the statement.

Let $R$ be any ring and let $M$ be a $R$-module of finite length, then $M$ has a composition series and the composition factors are uniquely determined up to permutation.

Now let $I \leq S$ be a non-zero ideal. I'll claim that $S/I$ is a finite-length module over $R$. Take any non-zero $a \in I$. Then $S/I$ is a quotient of $S/aS$, so it suffices to show that $S/aS$ has finite length over $R$. Because $S/R$ is an integral extension of domains, $aS \cap R$ is non-zero, so take $b \in aS \cap R$ non-zero, then $S/aS$ is a quotient of $S/bS$, so we may assume that $a \in R$. Now $S/aS$ is a finitely-generated $R/aR$-module, because $S$ if finitely generated over $R$, so it suffices to show that $R/aR$ is a finitely-generated $R$-module. The $R$-submodules of $R/aR$ are the same as $R/aR$-submodules (i.e. ideals), so it suffices to show that $R/aR$ is of finite-length over itself, i.e. an Artinian ring. Now $R$ is Noetherian and hence so is $R/aR$. The Krull dimension of $R$ is $1$ and $R$ is an domain, so every non-zero prime ideal of $R$ is maximal. But this implies that every prime ideal of $R/aR$ is maximal (as prime ideals of $R/aR$ correspond to prime ideals containing $a$, which is non-zero) and hence $R/aR$ has Krull dimension zero. Noetherian and Krull dimension zero is equivalent to Artinian, so we're done.
This means that we can apply the Jordan-Hölder theorem to the $R$-module $S/I$. Now we define the ideal norm $N_{S/R}(I)$ as follows:
Take a composition series for $S/I$ as an $R$-module. Each composition factor is of the form $R/\mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \leq R$, being a simple module. Now if the composition factors of $S/I$ are $R/\mathfrak{m}_1, R/\mathfrak{m}_2, \ldots, R/\mathfrak{m}_n$ (where in general some of the $\mathfrak{m}_i$ may be equal), we define $N_{S/R}(I)$ as the ideal product $$\mathfrak{m}_1 \cdot \mathfrak{m}_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot \mathfrak{m}_n$$
The Jordan-Hölder theorem implies that this is well-defined. It's straightforward to show that for $R=\Bbb Z$, the ideal norm $N_{S/\Bbb Z}(I)$ is just the cardinality $|S/I|$. (Think about how cardinalities behave in exact sequences.)
With this definition, we can state the generalized theorem:
Let $R,S,K,L$ as above and let $I \leq S$ be a non-zero ideal. Then $N_{S/R}(I)$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by the set $\{N_{L/K}(a) \mid a \in I\}$.
Proof We may assume without loss of generality that $I\neq S$ as $N_{L/K}(1)=1$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a non-zero prime ideal of $R$. We'll show that $\mathfrak{p}$ divides $N_{S/R}(I)$ with the same multiplicity as $\langle N_{L/K}(a) \mid a \in I\rangle$. From the definition of $N_{S/R}$, the multiplicity  of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $N_{S/R}(I)$ is the number of times that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ appears as a composition factor of $S/I$, which is equivalently the length of $R/\mathfrak{p} \otimes_R S/I$. Let's call this number $m_{\mathfrak{p}}$. We have an isomorphism
$$R/\mathfrak{p} \otimes_R S/I \cong R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_{R_{\mathfrak{p}}} S_{\mathfrak{p}}/IS_{\mathfrak{p}}$$.
This implies that the multiplicity with which $\mathfrak{p}$ divides $N_{S/R}(I)$ is the multiplicity with which $\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ divides $N_{S_{\mathfrak{p}}/R_{\mathfrak{p}}}(IS_{\mathfrak{p}})$
On the other hand, the multiplicity with which $\mathfrak{p}$ divides $\langle N_{L/K}(a) \mid a \in I\rangle$ is the same as the multiplicity with which $\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ divides $\langle N_{L/K}(a) \mid a \in I\rangle R_{\mathfrak{p}}$. The latter is equal to the ideal of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ generated by $\langle N_{L/K}(a) \mid a \in IS_{\mathfrak{p}}\rangle$.
Taken together, the arguments so far allow us to reduce us to the case that $R=R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a DVR. In this case $S=S_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a Dedekind domain with finitely many prime ideals (as there are only finitely many prime ideals in $S$ above $\mathfrak{p}$) and hence a PID. Thus after this reduction step, $I$ is a principal ideal $I=(a)$ for some $a \in S$ and our goal is to show that $(N_{L/K}(a))=N_{S/R}(I)$.
Take a prime factorization of $a$ in $S$: $a=q_1^{k_1}q_2^{k_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot q_w^{k_w}$. The Chinese remainder theorem implies that $N_{S/R}(aS)=\prod_{i=1}^w N_{S/R}(q_i^{k_i}S)$. The element-wise norm is multiplicative, hence we may assume that $a=q_1^{k_1}$ is the power of a prime element $q_1=q$ in $S$. Using inductively the short exact sequence $0 \to S/q^{k-1}S \to S/q^kS \to S/qS \to 0$, we see that the composition factors of $S/q^k$ are the same as the composition factors of $S/q$, except with their multiplicity multiplies by $k$, so that $N_{S/R}(q^kS)=N_{S/R}(qS)^k$. Again using the multiplicativity of the element-wise norm is multiplicative, it suffices to show that $N_{S/R}(qS)=(N_{L/K}(q))$.
But $N_{S/R}(qS)=\mathfrak{p}^{f(qS|\mathfrak{p})}$ ($f$ denoting inertia degree), because the length of $S/qS$ as an $R$-module will just be its dimension as a $R/\mathfrak{p}$-vector space.
On the other hand, at this point we may localize $S$ further at $qS$ so that we can assume $S$ is a DVR as well. But then if $(p)=\mathfrak{p}$ we get $p=uq^e$ for some unit $u \in S^\times$, but then $p^{[L:K]}=N_{L/K}(p)=N_{L/K}(u)N_{L/K}(q)^e$, so that upon taking ideals (using that $(N_{L/K}(u))=(1)$), we get that $(N_{L/K}(q))=\mathfrak{p}^{[L:K]/e(q|p)}=\mathfrak{p}^{f(q|p)}$, where the last step used the fundamental equation $[L:K]=f(q|p)e(q|p)$. This shows $N_{S/R}(qS)=(N_{L/K}(q))$, which finishes the proof.
Admittedly, there is an easier proof in the case that $R=\Bbb Z$ (which can be probably found in several ressources on algebraic number theory. I learned it in a graduate number theory course.) and maybe an even easier proof in the imaginary quadratic case, but I found it interesting to work out the case for general extensions of Dedekind domains.

Thanks for your detailed answer! Nevertheless, I also would like to explicitly see how the theory works in the mentioned case of a reduced ideal $I$ of the integer ring in the imaginary quadratic field. In other words, how to express the norm $n = a$ through the sum of some elements of $\mathrm{N}(I)$ with integer coefficients?

@DimitriKoshelev Maybe section 7.4 in Borevich and Shafarevich's Number Theory would help you.  See (7.8).  Also the totally different method of computing the norm of an ideal from its generators by "Kronecker's method" is nice: see the accepted answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26549/is-there-much-difference-between-kroneckers-and-dedekinds-methods-in-algebraic.
